# Asking about future events

Tags: tense, modal-verbs, questions, future-tense

Suppose I want to ask a listener about whether future action happened.

I think the following construction isn't suit for the case

> Will this action happened in the future?

Because I think ***will something/somebody + infinitve*** is used for giving order. Is the future progressive more suitable for the case?

Comment: By definition future actions can't have happened yet.  You might ask whether they **will** happen: *Will this action happen in the future?* or *Is this action going to happen?*

Comment: @Jim But M Swan in the practical Englsih usage says that with a verb reffering to an action, will you + infinitive usually introduced an order or request. So I guess the future progressive is common in the case.

Comment: But that's "*will **you***" not "*will*"   But you are correct, the sentence "Will you open the door?" could either be a request, a command, or a question about a future action.  Only context can tell you which.

Comment: @Jim Can the future progresive be used in such the case? I mean **Will** this action **be happening** in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence

> Will this action **happened** in the future?

contains a grammatic error: **Will** is a modal verb, and may only be followed by a verb in the infinitive: `will + happen` not `will *happened`.

Hence, the proper form is

> Will this action happen in the future?

Regarding your mention of the use of this construction in orders and requests: it depends on which words you use, and on the situation.

> Will **somebody/you/anybody** open the window?

is likely to be a request or order, while

> Will **this strong wind** open the window?

is clearly neither a request nor order, unless Strong Wind is the name of a person.

> Will **summer** follow the spring?

is unlikely to be a request, whereas

> Will **you** follow this red car?

is pretty likely to be one, especially if said to a taxi driver by a passenger.

Comment: Could you possibly explain can the Future Prog be used in such case?

Comment: The progressive form is used to stress the fact that the process is ongoing, that is has some duration. It will change the meaning, sometimes drastically. You'd better ask a separate question on that, with examples of sentences you want to change into the progressive.

Comment: But M. Swan says that the future progressive is also used to refer to future events (without progressive meaning) which are fixed or decided.

Comment: I think that "Will this action be happening in the future?" refers to something happening over a period of time. The meaning could be different with other kinds of verbs, I'm not that savvy in grammar to answer straight away. (0:

Comment: Minor, minor nitpick: when presenting multiple options in English, we use the forward slash / rather than the backslash \.